# Swift tapCreate() auto enable after disabled

Tags: macos, swift3

I have created tap with:

```
 guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cgSessionEventTap,
                                               place: .headInsertEventTap,
                                               options: .defaultTap,
                                               eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
                                               callback: myCGEventCallback,
                                               userInfo: nil) else {
                                               logger.info("failed to create event tap")
                                               exit(1)
                                             }
```

And my app works as expected. My app may also lock the machine during at any moment after the `tapCreate()` like this:

```
let task = Process()
task.arguments = ["-suspend"]
task.launchPath = "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession"
task.launch()
```

After going to the login screen with the above code and login back in, the tap created above is closed with this [exit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype/tapdisabledbytimeout).

I have been unsuccessful at finding a login hook or a way to recreate my `tap` once the user has logged back in. How can I restart the `tap` in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to get a notification when the user logs back in. This is only triggered when the user who launched the app logs back in. In `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, I have added:

```
NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rebuildEventChains(aNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActive, object: nil);
```

with function to be called upon login:

```
func rebuildEventChains(aNotification : NSNotification){
    // re-enable the tap if is disabled
    // ...
}
```